# How can I compare these two strings and remove a common letter without using arrays?

Tags: java, string

This was the code I designed to solve this problem but it seems not to work at all.I used nested for loops to compare the letters of the first string and the second string since they are likely to have different lengths

```
import java.util.*;
public class Trim
{
    public static String myTrim(String input, String list)
    {
        String r = "";
        for (int i = 1; i < input.length();i++)
        {
            for (int k = 1; k < list.length();k++)
            {
                if (input.charAt(i) != list.charAt(i))
                {
                    r += input.charAt(i);
                }
            }
        }
        return r;
     }

}
```

[image]

Comment: Why aren't you using k at all? The given problem description appears to ask about any character in list appearing in input anywhere, not only at the same position.

Comment: What exactly are you asking? For a simpler way? For a faster way? If your code doesn't give the expected output? The snippet posted however has some basic errors. Java generally has `0` as the first index, and you don't use the `k` variable.

Comment: "it seems not to work at all" -> What's the error / output you get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you should use the method `String.indexOf`.
So:

```
public static String myTrim(String input, String list)
{
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    char          c;
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++)
    {
      c = input.charAt(i);
      if (list.indexOf(c) < 0)
        result.append(c);
    }
    return result.toString();
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using a flag to determine whether to character gets repeated or not:

```
String r = "";
for (int i = input.length() - 1; 0 <= i; i --) {
  if (-1 == list.indexOf(input.charAt(i))) {
    r +=  input.charAt(i);
  }
}
```

OR

```
String r = "";
boolean found;
for (int i = input.length() - 1, j = list.length() - 1; 0 <= i; i--) {
  found = false;
  for (int k = j; 0 <= k; k--) {
    if (list.charAt(k) == input.charAt(i)) {
      found = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (!found) {
    r += input.charAt(i);
  }
}
```

Comment: You can't use arrays! :)

Answer (score 1):

> 1. We have to filter out the characters from input which appears in list.
> 2. Now we have to check whether each character of the input appears in the list or not.
> 3. The k value will be less then list.length() if the character of input present in the list string.
> 4. After the loop we check the k value and append it to the new string.

```
    public static String myTrim(String input, String list)
    {
        String r = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length();i++)
        {
                int k = 0;
            for (; k < list.length();k++)
            {
                if (input.charAt(i) == list.charAt(k))
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(k == list.length())
                r += input.charAt(i);
        }
        return r;
     }
```

Comment: by adding..I mean you should add with your answer so it can more readable and helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this code and it's working fine with both of your inputs

```
for (int i = 0; i < S1.length(); i++) {

        for(int j=0;j< S2.length();j++) {

            if(S1.charAt(i)==S2.charAt(j)) {

                char Temp= S2.charAt(j);
                String Temp2=String.valueOf(Temp);

            S1=S1.replace(Temp2, "");
            }
        }

    }
```

This is code

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class StringRemoveChar {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String S1, S2;

        S1 = scanner.nextLine();
        S2 = scanner.nextLine();

        for (int i = 0; i < S1.length(); i++) {

            for (int j = 0; j < S2.length(); j++) {
                if (S1.charAt(i) == S2.charAt(j)) {
                    char Temp = S2.charAt(j);
                    String Temp2 = String.valueOf(Temp);
                    S1 = S1.replace(Temp2, "");
                    System.out.println(S1.length());
                }
            }

        }
        System.out.println(S1);

    }

}
```

Input:

> Miyazaki
>   you

Output:

> Miazaki

Comment: This gives me out of range errors if s1 and s2 have nonidentical lengths

Comment: Please provide me test cases because i executed this code on both the examples given in questions which are not identical and it working fine.I hope that you have tried to execute  before commenting

Comment: Sorry, it ended up working. I had problems when I was trying to receive the first String as input from the keyboard. I just figured I just needed to type the string directly into the method. Thanks boss!

Answer (score 0):

A nice one-liner solution would be to use [Guava Charmatcher](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/CharMatcher.html):

```
CharMatcher.anyOf(list).removeFrom(input);
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use replaceAll and use one loop over ,this will make the solution simple

```
public static String myTrim(String input, String list)
    { 
        for(int i=0;i<list.length();i++)
        {
            input=input.replaceAll(list.charAt(i)+"","");
        }

        return input;
     }
```

Input: myTrim("Miyazaki","you")

Output: Miazaki

Full code for reference

```
package stackoverflow.string;

public class StringManipulation
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        System.out.println(myTrim("University of Miami","city"));

    }


        public static String myTrim(String input, String list)
        { 
            for(int i=0;i<list.length();i++)
            {
                input=input.replaceAll(list.charAt(i)+"","");
            }

            return input;
         }

}
```

Comment: I did the same thing but when you try with a phrase like {University of Miami} it just returns {Univers}

Comment: I am able to get the proper output which is Unvers of Mam , Can you run the full code and check i have updated my answer

Comment: Thanks! I have sorted it out